# Windows 10 USB boot is stuck in loading screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-installation

I am trying to replace Ubuntu in my c drive(other two partition are also NTFS) with windows 10 but bootable USB is stuck in loading screen with or without the hard drive ,what to do, thanks

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use drive letters. If you want to install Windows prepare a proper USB stick preferably in Windows and using the official tool.

Comment: I have prepared windows bootable from another windows PC which works fine on another pc